# Change <input> font size based on parent text tag

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a "Natural Language" form like [this one](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1007) and therefore I include the `<input>` tags right inside the text like this:

```
<h3>I am <input type="number" /> years old.</h3
```

I'd like to know if there is an easy way to set the font-size of this input to be the same as the text (in this case h3)? That way I could include it inside h1's, h2's, etc. without worrying about font-size.

The main reason being that I use Bootstrap for my typography, and it does a lot of magic which I'd want to automagically apply to my input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `font-size:inherit;` to make the font size match it's parent.

HTML

```
<h3>I am <input class="inherit" type="number" /> years old.</h3>
```

CSS

```
.inherit {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/uyxr7zm0/

Comment: Nice one, and very simple.

Comment: Absolutely correct, it turns out I tried this but it didn't work for another reason related to some of my code. Thanks!

Comment: @FlorianBienefelt If this answer solved your question, van you mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left. That way, it won't show up in the list of unanswered questions any more.